# RPM Measurement (rotary Encoder)

Tags: signal, dc-motor, encoder

I am measuring Dc motor RPM using a rotary encoder(custom made).The input supply to the encoder is 3.3v and the encoder output(Sine wave) is given to the Schmitt trigger to get square shaped signal.
I read this signal through a microcontroller for controlling the motor.

I have few question regarding this.

The length of the wire which I use to transfer the signal from encoder to PCB board(microcontroller) is 5 meter.Is this a problem 3.3v signal travelling for 5mts?
If so, then I have a 5v supply in the board can I use that instead of 3.3v?

If I am using a 5v instead of 3.3v should I have to use levelshifter(Again Microcontroller uses 3.3v control)?What kind of level shifter can I use for this?

Additional information:
Encoder Signal Frequency : 2-5khz

Any idea??

Answer (score 1):

As there is very little current involved then the resistance of a few metres of cable is not a problem (voltage drop) **BUT** it may pick up all sorts of noise. Make sure you use a screened cable.

Comment: Thanks@JIm Dearden I will sure do that.I have a doubt on using this screened or shielded cable!!.I have crimp connector on both the end of the wire and if i introduce the shielded cable how will i connect the shied to the ground, should i crimp or any other way?(and the connector will be removed multiple times.)

Comment: I think it is good practice to increase that current through the encoder with small'ish resistors. The encoder is probably little more than a couple switches to ground and the wire will pick up noise when the wire is floating.